In TypeScript how might one create a mapped, conditional type that removes properties of type string | null
Here's my final failed attempt before coming here for advice. What am I doing wrong pls ty?
interface Something {
  id: string;
  name: string | null;
}

interface AnotherThing {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

type ExcludeNullableFields<A> = {
  [K in keyof A as A[K] extends string | null ? K : never]: A[K] ;
};

type NamelessThing = ExcludeNullableFields<Something>; 
// desired outcome: { id: string }

type NamedThing = ExcludeNullableFields<AnotherThing>; 
// desired outcome: { id: string; name: string }


fairs do's for the -1 vote, I did rush the question as I was pushed for time. Apols. Thanks anyway to Scott and Scerdi

If you tweak ExcludeNullableFields to this..
type ExcludeNullableFields<A> = {
  [K in keyof A as Extract<A[K], null> extends  never ? K : never]: A[K] ;
};

Basically I'm checking to see if I can extract null from any of the types. If a type doesn't contain null, then extract will return never.  But if Extract does find the type null then I know a field is nullable.

Your ExcludeNullableFields conditional type is currently including fields that are of type string | null, instead of excluding them. You need to change the logic in your conditional:
type ExcludeNullableFields<A> = {
  [K in keyof A as A[K] extends string ? K : never]: A[K];
};

type NamelessThing = ExcludeNullableFields<Something>; 
// result: { id: string }

type NamedThing = ExcludeNullableFields<AnotherThing>; 
// result: { id: string; name: string }

Hope this helps.

thx @Skerdi Velo your answer is simpler and therefore more attractive at first glance but what I'm trying to do is exclude nulls not include strings, but thank you anyway and maybe your answer will help someone else
